# How do I set the number of tiles on Firefox's new tab page?

Tags: firefox

The Firefox 33 upgrade changed me to having only six tiles on the page instead of 9, so I can't see all of the pinned tabs I had before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official way is to edit these two properties in your about:config page:

- browser.newtabpage.columns
- browser.newtabpage.rows

But if you are missing tiles just since you upgraded the browser, try using `Ctrl + minus` to zoom out. Your tiles should still be there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug that's still around - these settings are ignored and the page randomly switches between the zoom set and the default zoom. Ctrl+- and Ctrl++ will change the zoom on the current newtab but the next one opened may or may not have the correct zoom (switch away and refocus the tab can even change the zoom).